# How do i divide BigIntegers in kotlin? (I have tried div() and divideAndRemainder())

Tags: java, android, kotlin, biginteger

I am trying to divide two Big Integer values and it does not seem to be working. I have tried **BigIntegervalue1.div(BigIntegervalue2)** and **BigIntegervalue1.divideAndRemainder(BigIntegervalue2)**. I am getting a **type mismatch Error** when I thought I could declare remainder and quotient with divideAndRemainder which would give me BigInteger

Here is the full code:

```
package converter
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.util.*
var alphabet = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")

fun convertNumberToDecimal(numberToConvert: String, sourceBase: Int): String { // fix this formula!
  var finalValue = ""
  var elementHolder = (numberToConvert).toMutableList()
  var i = elementHolder.size - 1
  var j = 0
  var decimalNumber = 0.toString()
  while (i != -1) {
    if (elementHolder.isEmpty()) {
      break
    } else if (elementHolder[j].toString() in alphabet) {
      elementHolder[j] = (9 + alphabet.indexOf(elementHolder[j].toString())).toChar()
      decimalNumber += (elementHolder[j].toInt() * Math.pow(sourceBase.toDouble(), i.toDouble()).toInt()).toString()
      println(decimalNumber)
    } else {
      decimalNumber += (elementHolder[j].toInt() * Math.pow(sourceBase.toDouble(), i.toDouble()).toInt()).toString()
    }
    j++
    i--
  }
  return decimalNumber
}

fun convertDecimalToNewBase(numberToConvert: String, targetBase: Int): Any {
  var checker = 0
  var i = 0
  var power = targetBase
  var sumOfNumbers = 0
  var decimalNumber: Any
  if (numberToConvert[0] == '0') {
    decimalNumber = BigInteger(numberToConvert.drop(1))
  } else {
    decimalNumber = BigInteger(numberToConvert)
  }
  var listOfNumbers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
  var finalValue = ""
  var denominator = BigInteger("0")
  
  while (checker < numberToConvert.toInt()) {
    checker = Math.pow(targetBase.toDouble(), i.toDouble()).toInt()
    i++
    if (checker > numberToConvert.toInt()) {
      i -= 2
      checker = Math.pow(targetBase.toDouble(), i.toDouble()).toInt()
      break
    }
  }
  
  while (i != -1) {
    denominator = (Math.pow(targetBase.toDouble(), i.toDouble())).toInt().toBigInteger()
    var (quotient, remainder) = decimalNumber.divideAndRemainder(denominator)
    if (quotient.toInt() >= 10 && quotient.toInt() <= 36 && targetBase > 10) {
      quotient = alphabet[(quotient.toInt() - 10)]
    }
    listOfNumbers.add(quotient)
    decimalNumber = remainder
    i--
  }
    
  for (each in listOfNumbers) {
    finalValue += each.toString()
  }
  for (each in alphabet) {
    if (each in finalValue) {
      return finalValue
    }
  }
  return finalValue.toBigInteger()
}

fun main() {
  var scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
  println("Enter two numbers in format: {source base} {target base} (To quit type /exit) ")
  var choice = readLine()!!.toString()
  var splitter = listOf<String>()
  var sourceBase: Int
  var targetBase: Int
  var numberInSourceBase: Any
  var newDecimalNumber: Any
  if (choice == "/exit") {
    exitProcess(0)
  } else {
    splitter = choice.split(" ")
    sourceBase = splitter[0].toInt()
    targetBase = splitter[1].toInt()
  }
  do {
    println("Enter number in base " + sourceBase + " to convert to base " + targetBase + " (To go back type /back) ")
    numberInSourceBase = readLine()!!.toString()
    if (numberInSourceBase == "/back") {
      main()
    }
    if (sourceBase != 10) {
      newDecimalNumber = convertNumberToDecimal(numberInSourceBase.toString(), sourceBase)
      newDecimalNumber = (convertDecimalToNewBase(newDecimalNumber.toString(), targetBase)).toString()
    } else {
      newDecimalNumber = (convertDecimalToNewBase(numberInSourceBase.toString(), targetBase)).toString()
    }
    println("Conversion result: " + newDecimalNumber)
  } while (numberInSourceBase != "/back")
}
```

Here is the line of code that is giving me the type mismatch error:

```
var (quotient, remainder) = decimalNumber.divideAndRemainder(denominator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and I got a different error. Which is

```
Unresolved reference: divideAndRemainder
```

Which is simply because `decimalNumber` doesn't have that method. Why doesn't it have that method while only `BigIntegers` are assigned to it? simply because it isn't declared as one.

Changing

```
var decimalNumber: Any
```

to

```
var decimalNumber: BigInteger
```

removes that error.

Now there are other errors showing, which is up to you how to solve